# Can we run two system dbus processes of different version?

Tags: gtk, d-bus, gtk3

I have two installations of gtk and dbus:

1. The default system installation of version which is not supported for meld.
2. Shared installation of version that supports meld and for use across
   different machines.

I have got the following error when I invoke meld tool:

`WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files`

So, I thought it's something to do with dbus.
I started the dbus with custom init.d script:

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
. /NFS_share/meld_3_16_0.profile #script to set meld env path>
/NFS_share/meld/meld_3_16_0/bin/dbus-uuidgen --ensure
daemon --check messagebus_1.8 dbus-daemon --system
touch /var/lock/subsys/messagebus_1.8

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
dbus_1.8 24972     1  0 18:23 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system
```

user is `dbus_1.8` and group is `dbus`:

```
# id -a dbus_1.8
uid=2881(dbus_1.8) gid=81(dbus) groups=81(dbus)
```

Reason for using different user is I thought that it might create conflict between the default running dbus system process and the new process.

My question is how can the dbus client process of meld application knows which dbus system process to connect and is the username of the dbus important (can we give any username)?